# .net Core 3.1 C# MVC An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to bind an array of objects in a view model from the view to send back to the controller to post to a db.  I am populating a select list as follows in the ViewModel in ContactForm:

```
       public List<SelectListItem> PhoneTypes { get; } = new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Not Specified", Text = "Not Specified"},
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Cell", Text = "Cell"},
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Home", Text = "Home"}
        };
```

In my controller I am sending the viewmodel to the view as follows:

```
        ContactInfoViewModel civm = new ContactInfoViewModel();

        List<ContactForm> tpl = new List<ContactForm>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            tpl.Add(new ContactForm());
        }
        civm.ContactForms = tpl;
```

In my view I am looping through to bind the contactform objects from the List in the form.  It works fine if I comment out the select line.

```
        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms.Count; i++)
        {

            <label asp-for="ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms[i].Name"></label>  <input asp-for="ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms[i].Name" />
            <label asp-for="ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms[i].Phone"></label>  <input asp-for="ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms[i].Phone" />
            <label asp-for="ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms[i].PhoneType"></label>  <select asp-for="ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms[i].PhoneType" asp-items="ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms[i].PhoneTypes"></select>
            <label asp-for="ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms[i].Relationship"></label>  <input asp-for="ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms[i].Relationship" />
            <br />
        }
```

The select list line above gives this error:

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms'

Any ideas how I can get this select list to work?  I don't understand why this select list is different than any other of the elements in the contact form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Model.ContactInfoViewModel.ContactForms[i].Name` etc?

Comment: @JohanP Thanks for the tip.  All the ASP For Tag helpers error out if I use Model with a does not contain definition for Model.  However, I forgot asp-items does need the full reference.  Adding model for that asp-items solved it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-select-tag-helper